# Jquery .remove() only acts on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm building out a notifications feature with bootstrap popover. A notification should be removed after a user clicks on it, which is intuitive. However, it takes two clicks to make it work -- the first time, nothing seems to happen. The click listener is firing both times as discovered through alert().

I've simplified my problem to its most basic reproducible form in this fiddle js:
https://jsfiddle.net/ksun78/758n1azu/36/

```js
$('body').on("click", ".popover-body .notif-popup-container", function() {
  $("#" + $(this).attr("id")).remove();
})
```

Placing code above because it won't let me submit without code snippet, though the fiddle js should have all you need.

Can someone explain what the issue might be and how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: That's because the popover makes a copy of the elements. And ids must be unique. So the first time it selects the first one, the next time it selects the second one. Doing `$("#" + $(this).attr("id"))` doesn't make much sense, does it?

Comment: `$("#" + $(this).attr("id")).remove();` If you know the phone number of someone, do you call them to ask them what their phone number is and then re-call them? You can simply do `$(this).remove();` which removes the "double click" issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that behind the scenes, popover will make a copy of the elements and display them. This means that using ONLY the ID to remove the elements won't work, because it will first remove the display:none element on the page, then the copy of that shown in the popover. Thanks to @Gabriel for pointing that out.

The solution here was just to not use the id attribute of the element as it was unnecessary. A simple $(this).remove() will do the trick.

As for the issue of duplicate id's: I was originally intending on storing the notification id inside a "data-id" attribute. However, retrieving "data-id" using jquery was returning undefined, so I opted for the "id" attribute instead. Maybe @Gabriel can provide some insight into the issue of "data-id" being undefined, as it seems like a popover related issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the popover library clones your elements so there are two elements with the same Ids. You can modify your code like this so it will work but better to avoid same Ids

```
$('body').on("click", ".popover-body .notif-popup-container", function() {
  $(`[id="${$(this).attr("id")}"]`).remove();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to delete that div you can use following code:

```
$(document).on("click", ".notif-popup-container", function() {
  $(this).remove();
});
```